# jquery datatables show/hide column adds wrong select

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable having 9 columns. I am using following two functions to show/hide certain columns of my table.

```
    function fnShow( iCol )
        {
            var oTable = $('#companies').dataTable();
            oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, true );

        }

      function fnHide( iCol )
        {
            var oTable = $('#companies').dataTable();
            oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, false );

        }
```

And this is how am calling these function to show/hide based on certain conditions:

```
    if(document.getElementById("type").value=='Dispensary Sick Bay')
        {fnShow(9);}
    else
        {fnShow(2);fnShow(3);fnShow(4);fnShow(5);}
```

AND

```
    if(document.getElementById("type").value=='Dispensary Sick Bay')
     {fnHide(9);}
      else
     {fnHide(2);fnHide(3);fnHide(4);fnHide(5);}
```

**Now the problem is when I hide columns 2, 3, 4, 5 their associated dropdown lists for EDITABLE appear for columns 6, 7, 8 9 which is in noway acceptable.** :/

I searched it a lot on net but didn't find even a single related post. :o

Hope to see some solution by you people.

Regards.

Comment: Not sure but try redrawing datatables on third argument, `oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, false, true);` A fiddle, perhaps?

Comment: the third value, if skipped, is by-default true. However, I tried with 'true' but it ain't working either :/ my bad....

Comment: Anyone to answer? :/

Answer (score 0):

I do it slightly differently and works for me...

I show all then just hide what I don't want instead of two functions

```
var oTable = $('#companies').dataTable({
  "columnDefs": [
    {
      "targets": [ iCol ],
      "visible": false
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: "columnDefs" doesn't work with dataTable. It is for DataTables.

Comment: You've tagged `DataTables`!

Comment: The tag is datatables and the code says its dataTables. :) Thanks anyways for your contribution.

Comment: Anyone to answer? :/